# Prove existence of local extrema for function $f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ on a open set.

Tags: calculus, optimization

I would like to prove the existence of local extrema for a function $f(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ on a open set, where $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ are given to be positive real numbers. Plus, I cannot find critical points through the first order conditions as I can't solve the system explicitly. In this case, what would be the procedures to take to show there exist a local extremum.

Comment: Is there more to the question? There aren't necessarily any local extrema. Consider $f\colon \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x) = x$.

Comment: You typically need to know something about the behavior of the function as you approach the boundary of the domain.

Comment: Thanks. Could you give some scenarios that a local extrema would exist?